# What permissions do I need to POST a like for a user?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm POSTing a like for a user's photo using the following code (in the Android SDK):

```
params = new Bundle();
params.putString(Facebook.TOKEN, values.getString(Facebook.TOKEN));
json = facebook.request(photoUpload.id + "/likes", params, "POST");
```

But the response I get back is:

```
{"error":
    {"type":"OAuthException",
     "message":"(#200) Permissions error"}
}
```

But I already *have* the `publish_stream` permission.  Do I need a different permission?  Another one?

Comment: Did you ever solve this one? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

`publish_stream` is the correct one for wall posts.  I would also try `user_photos` since you are trying to like a photo.  Wonder if you are running into some temporary Facebook issue.

> publish_stream:
>   **Enables your app to post content, comments, and likes** to a user's
>   stream and to the streams of the user's friends. With this permission,
>   you can publish content to a user's feed at any time, without
>   requiring offline_access. However, please note that Facebook
>   recommends a user-initiated sharing model.